# Escaping ' (single quote) in sed replace string

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

I have a script that I'm using to perform some iptables changes across servers. In the script I have a sed command to find a string and insert iptables rule before that line.

The problem I'm having is that the file I'm editing is a yaml file and I need to have a ' and ' in the line.

If I remove the ' from what I'm inserting, it works.

```
$ sed 's/.*output_snat_lo.conf:.*/- -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1\n&/' file.yaml


     - '-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.25/32 -d 10.0.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source 172.1.1.1'
     - -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1
  output_snat_lo.conf:
```

However, if I try to escape it with slashes or putting it within double quotes, double quotes with slashes I can't get the ' to print but rather give send invalid flag options.

This is what I'm trying to insert.

```
- '-t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1'\n&/' file.yaml
```

Any suggestions/tricks? I feel like I've done this in the past but can't recall how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

close the single quote you are putting the regexp in, escape a single quote, and open it again

```
$ echo "a'b" | sed 's/'\''/X/'
aXb

$ echo "aXb" | sed 's/X/'\''/'
a'b
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape in sed, where `'` has no special significance.  You need to escape it in bash.

```
$ sed -e "s/'/singlequote/g" <<<"'"
singlequote
```

You can see here that the double quotes protect the single quote from bash, and sed does fine with it.  Here's what happens when you switch the single quotes.

```
$ sed -e 's/'/singlequote/g' <<<"'"
>
```

The strange thing about `'` in bourne like shells (all?) is that it functions less like `"` and more like a flag to disable other character interpretation until another `'` is seen. If you enclose it in double quotes it won't have it's special significance.  Observe:

```
$ echo 'isn'"'"'t this hard?'
isn't this hard?
```

You can also escape it with a backslash as shown in the other answer.  But you have to *leave* the single quoted block before that will work.  So while this seems like it would work:

```
echo '\''
```

it does not; the first `'` disables the meaning of the `\` character.

I suggest you take a different approach. `sed` expressions can be specified as command line arguments - but at the expense of having to escape from the shell.  It's not bad to escape a short and simple sed expression, but yours is pretty long and has a lot of special characters.

I would put your `sed` command in a file, and invoke `sed` with the `-f` argument to specify the command file instead of specifying it at the command line. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html or `man sed` will go into detail.  This way the `sed` commands aren't part of what the shell sees (it only sees the filename) and the shell escaping conundrum disappears.

```
$ cat t.sed
s/'*/singlequote(s)/g

$ sed -f t.sed <<<"' ' '''"
singlequote(s) singlequote(s) singlequote(s)
```