# Problem with variable and quotes in script including sed command

Tags: bash, sed, grub2

I am trying to do this script to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
win_location=$(cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep 'class windows' | cut -d "'" -f2)
sudo sed -i 's/^'GRUB_DEFAULT='.*$/GRUB_DEFAULT="$win_location"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub2
```

But the problem is it does not recognizes the variable, which should be printed between quotes to the file because its value include spaces.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping ' (single quote) in sed replace string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542454/escaping-single-quote-in-sed-replace-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables into the sed, please use double quotes instead of single quotes

As per your example, you have variables in sed

```
sudo sed -i "s|^GRUB_DEFAULT=.*$|GRUB_DEFAULT=\"$win_location\"|g" /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: Using double quotes around the `sed` expression has nothing to do with its use in a script. If you want to expand shell variables in the expression, then you need double quotes instead of single quotes. Also, a single quoted string can never contain a single quote, which is another reason for using double quotes. The delimiter does not _need_ to be a pipe character. (almost) Any character would do fine. An explanation of why `/` may be a problematic character to use would be in order.

Comment: I agree with you, my theory was wrong, apart of that the above is working.

Comment: So change your answer to accommodate for the comments you've received, as it is still a wrong answer without the changes.